# Do multiple Java references double the memory used?

Tags: java, memory, reference

I have recently learned how to create multiple references to the same mutable object in Java, which I am employing in a compound list of my creation. My question is, am I doubling my memory usage, or just using an additional int as a memory address?
Here is the code to which I am specifically referring:

```
//This is my object containing a 64bit long
public class LongWrapper
{
    long data;
    LongWrapper(int data_in)
    {
        data = data_in;
    }
    public long getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(long data_in)
    {
        data = data_in;
    }
}

//This is my driver program containing references a & b
public class PointerTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        LongWrapper a = new LongWrapper(6);
        LongWrapper b = a;
        System.out.println("a = " + a.getData() + " b = " + b.getData());
        a.setData(7);
        System.out.println("a = " + a.getData() + " b = " + b.getData());
    }
}

This is my output:
a = 6 b = 6
a = 7 b = 7
```

So in this case what I think is happening in memory is that I have 2 references that are 32bit memory addresses, and one object containing my 64bit long; is this accurate?

I ask because I want to use much larger objects and this will allow my to have them in multiple lists whilst properly minimizing my memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in this case what I think is happening in memory is that I have 2
>   references that are 32bit memory addresses, and one object containing
>   my 64bit long; is this accurate?

You have one object and two references `a` and `b` to refer that object. That object has a long `data`.

You can alter/query the state of that object by using both references `a` and `b`.

Comment: ... and therefore you have one `long data`, since you have one object.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is spot on as to what I needed. I will upvote when my rep is up.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. However,  if your code is  running on a 64 bits architecture, references are 64 bits instead of 32 bits.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the prompt reply. I will upvote when my rep is up. The note on the 64bit address is very helpful and exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely are not doubling your memory usage. you can create as many references as you want pointing to the same object. The references are placed on the stack, and the single object on the heap. The object occupy more space than 64bit because this is only the memory allocated for its field

Comment: Thank you for the above and beyond notes; I am learning a lot from this site, and I appreciate it. I will upvote when I'm allowed to.